# How to insert user entered data into a local html document

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm very new to Swift and I'm struggling a bit with a simple task. I have made a simple app which will launch a local HTML file.

I now want to add a text box that appears, asking the user "Enter IP address". Then, that text will be inserted into the HTML file in 3 different places.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Or know of a good site which might have some tutorials which relate to this idea? Here's my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var htmlload: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        let htmlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlpath!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        htmlload.load(request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```